# How do I disable the update software message box with Tortoise SVN client

Tags: tortoisesvn

When using Tortoise SVN for the first time since a reboot, if the software has a new version, a message box appears asking to visit the website to get the new version. Does anyone know of a way to disable this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to the settings and disable the "Check for newer versions every week" checkbox.

Comment: And so it is, thanks. I guess I have not checked the settings in a while, didn't realize that was added :)

Comment: that wasn't added - it's been there ever since the upgrade check was there.

Comment: I'm not the only one who has had this problem: http://www.gamedev.net/features/reviews/productreview.asp?productid=747

Comment: Unfortunately this setting apparently has been removed in some later version. Now there is the "VersionCheck" option on the Advanced page.

Answer (score 6):

For newer versions of tortoisesvn

You will never get a popup. Instead the notification appears in an
otherwise blank area of the commit dialog, so it is less intrusive. If
you still find this a nuisance you can disable the check using
Settings->Advanced and set VersionCheck to false.

http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/ds/viewMessage.do?dsForumId=4061&dsMessageId=2976707&orderBy=createDate&orderType=desc

Answer (score 1):

Right click on any folder in Windows Explorer. Select `TortoiseSVN` > `Settings`. On `General` tab unselect `Automatically check for newer versions every week` checkbox.